# Fixing a couple aesthetic issues in an html bulleted list

Tags: html, css, vue.js

My current code displays:

[image]

I'm attempting to change it as follows:

1. Each line in the list should fit properly in the corresponding box, for which I've used `vertical-align: top`.
2. Moving the `40 kcal` and `30 kcal` to the rightmost of the box, for which I've used `text-align: right`.

Yet I seem unable to make either of the changes work.

---

```
<template>
  <h3> Foods: </h3>
  <ul class="food-list">
    <li class="food-item">
      <p class="left">Banana &nbsp;</p>
      <p class="right">40 kcal</p>
    </li>
    <li class="food-item">
      <p class="left">Strawberry &nbsp;</p>
      <p class="right">30 kcal</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<style scoped>
.food-list {
  width: 300px;
}

.food-item {
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
```

---

In case it is relevant, I'm using Vue + VueCLI.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for individual css on `left` and `right` classes. You can use `display: flex; justify-content: space-around;` on the `food-item` class and it would do the work for you. Also I don't understand the `margin: -10px` there.